# Fittings for conduit passing through ceiling/floor

Tags: cabling, conduit

A follow up to this question: [Running Coax cable to the upper floor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47481/running-coax-cable-to-the-upper-floor)

If I cut a hole in the ceiling of my dining room and then another in the floor so I can run a conduit from the upstairs all the way to the basement, what should I use to secure the top and bottom of the conduit so it doesn't just fall through to the basement!

I need some kind of clamp (or maybe a bushing?) that will secure the conduit at the top (either on the ceiling of the dining room or the floor of the attic) and then again either at the floor of the dining room or the ceiling of the basement. I know I can clamp it to the wall (assuming I can find the stud), but it still seems like I should secure the top and bottom or else it could slide vertically out.

Comment: Securing it to the wall with a conduit clamp should do it.  If it's not near a stud you attach a channel from stud to stud and secure the clamp to the channel.  Perhaps you are looking for a less ugly solution?

Comment: What type of conduit are you using?

Comment: @Tester101: I've not decided yet

Comment: Reading your previous post, it looks like you'll be sheeting over the conduit eventually, but you mention stud-framed wall behind the conduit.  why not run the wire/conduit inside the existing wall?  Also, they make flexible conduit for data lines, sometimes called "smurf tube" because it is blue.

Comment: @Paul: Because I figure it would be much easier to work *outside* the walls. Especially since it'll end up *inside* the wall eventually anyway.

Comment: Since this is for coax you can use any type of conduit you want. You really don't even need conduit unless you are thinking of having a raceway to run additional wire at a later time. Though you are really looking for a way to secure it. Any time of C-clamp for the conduit size would work fine. Should be in the same area as the conduit itself or close to.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of conduit used, the codes for securing and supporting it are a bit different.  In general, the conduit will have to be supported every 3-10 ft, depending on the type and size conduit used.

Fireblocking between floor may also be required.

> ## International Residential Code 2012
>
> ### Chapter 3 Building Planning
>
> #### Section 302 Fire Resistant Construction
>
> **R302.11 Fireblocking.** In combustible construction, fireblocking shall be provided to cut off all concealed draft openings (both vertical and horizontal) and to form an effective fire barrier between stories, and between a top story and the roof space.
>
> Fireblocking shall be provided in wood-frame construction in the following locations:
>
> *4.* At openings around vents, pipes, ducts, cables and wires at ceiling and floor level, with an approved material to resist the free passage of flame and products of combustion. The material filling this annular space shall not be required to meet the ASTM E 136 requirements

Comment: I've not seen any type of fireblocking done for any wiring/cable in houses I've owned/renovated and all passed inspections. Piping, ducts and vents I know need some type but wires/cables will depend on local code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use WireMold conduit (which isn't nearly as ugly as round conduit), you can screw the backing strip to drywall anchors, studs, whatever you have, then snap the conduit body on over the backing strip. That's about as anchored as it can get.

Comment: Surface raceways should not be confused with conduits -- you can't run the former in a concealed app!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel... I've only ever known WireMold as "conduit". True that it (or any other openable "wire contaier") should not be used in any fully concealed space. Fortunately, WireMold makes transitions ("connectors") for WireMold-to-conduit connections.

Comment: Since the OP notes this is for coax cable, this comment is fully valid. I don't see any reason for anyone to have -1 it.

Comment: @ClumsyHamster - ???